# .NET HTML DOM Parser?

Tags: .net, html, dom

Does anybody know of a freely available .NET HTML DOM Parser?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) is your friend. It's been very well tested (coping with tag soup as well as well-formed (X)HTML). I've also heard that people have had not had any issues using it in production applications.