# $(selector).text() equivalent in c# (Revised)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am trying check if the inner html of the element is empty but I wanted to do the validation on the server side, I'm treating the html as a string. Here is my code

```
public string HasContent(string htmlString){
    // this is the expected value of the htmlString

    //  <span class="spanArea">
    //      <STYLE>.ExternalClass234B6D3CB6ED46EEB13945B1427AA47{;}</STYLE>
    //  </span>

    // From this jquery code-------------->
    // if($('.spanArea').text().length>0){
    //  
    // }
    // <------------------
    // I wanted to convert the jquery statement above into c# code. 

    /// c# code goes here
    return htmlSTring;
}
```

using this line

```
$('.spanArea').text() // what is the equivalent of this line in c#
```

I will know if the .spanArea does really have something to display in the ui or not. I wanted to do the checking on the server side. No need to worry about how to I managed to access the DOM I have already taken cared of it. Consider the htmlString as the Html string.

My question is if there is any equivalent for this jquery line in C#?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: yes, I wanna check if the inner text of spanArea is not empty in code behind c#

Comment: Please post the code behind for page that's servicing your AJAX call.

Comment: C# runs on the server, it has no direct access to the DOM so your only option is having the desired element be server side by adding `runat="server"` then you can follow the other advices here. :)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Nay, in computing there is *always* a second option.

Comment: @yoda if you find a way to access DOM element directly with C# code you're really yoda! ;)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: AJAX is one possible solution.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: No need to worry about accessing the DOM elements, I have it already taken cared of using AJAX. I have revised my questions, my bad. :)

Comment: Please clarify if you are writing a webforms application or an mvc application, or something else entirely?

Comment: this is a sharepoint application actually Im using a webpart page and passing the DOM elements using ajax to a webform

Comment: @Ian that's still better be done client side - what you need it for? What will you do in case it's empty?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: yes I know life is easier if it is to be done in client side but in sharepoint not all inputs are done in the client side, it has the facility called out of the box that will pass directly to the list that's why I would need to validate these in the server side. Hope you get my point. :)

Comment: @Ian so I fear there's no escape from using server side HTML parser, see Protron answer.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard:Yes that's what I'm also thinking, that would be my last option. If our crazy manager would allow me to use it I would be very much delighted. That should work for me but the thing is he don't want me to use third party libraries (maybe for now), until he goes desperate lol... Somehow there should be some other ways, I will just try to experiment stuffs, I might hit the jackpot. :) A big thanks!

Comment: I think you ought to tell your manager that there's no way around the supreme collective intelligence of StackOverflow! Ergo, he should allow you to use a third-party component. :)

Comment: lol Guess what? He gave up and said "Ok slave how about let's try your idea about the HTML parser thing just make sure it's safe". If he could have told me earlier we shouldn't have wasted time. And a matter of an hour after that, the page worked as expected lol :). Damn these managers but not all, they sure are managers waiting for the good and dumping you all the bad stuffs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to get that data from the HTML in the ServerSide then I would recommend you to use a **Html-Parser** for that job.

If you check *[other SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857912/net-html-dom-parser)* you will find that **[Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples)** was recommended many times.

Answer (score 2):

Tag the SpanArea with runat="server" and you can then access it in the code behind:

```
<span id="mySpan" class="spanArea" runat="server" />
```

You can then:

```
string spanContent = mySpan.InnerText;
```

Comment: Someone care to explain the down vote? I assumed the op wants to check the span after a post back

Comment: it may be because of class name. you can remove the '.' from the classname since . represents class. so .spanArea means objects with class name "spanArea". If it was #spanArea it would mean object with id spanArea.

Comment: Somehow this kind of approach works but not on my end, I'm doing a webpart thing and I'm passing a pure html content as a string... are there other ways to do it? Thanks Luis for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code-behind for the page that includes this AJAX call will have already have executed (in presenting the page to the browser) before the AJAX call is ever executed so your question doesn't appear correct.

The code-behind that is delivering the HTML fragment you indicated is probably constructing that using a StringBuilder or similar so you should be able to verify in that code whether there is any data.

The fragment you provided only includes a `DIV`, a `SPAN` and a `STYLE` tag. This is all likely to collapse to a zero width element and display nothing.

Have a look at this article which will help you understand the [ASP.NET page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Comment: Why are you assuming that the op does not want to do the check during a postack?

Comment: Where does the OP indicate any Postback? There is a page that's generated that contains the javascript that makes an AJAX call to return the fragment in which the OP is looking to validate some of the content. If the OP owns the server page that's delivering the AJAX content then he can verify the data within needing to `runat="server"` as they're creating that segment. If not then then there's nothing that they can do in the code-behind of the main page as it's already executed and been disposed of.