# Using Regex to find everything between the center tags

Tags: regex

So I am using a vendor application that uses regex to cut out code from my site. I have an entire div that I want to find and remove using regex controls but when I try it the line breaks and divs get in my way. Does anyone have any ideas? I am trying .+? but like i said think with the line breaks and everything it stops it from gathering everything.

```
<center>
<div id="divSiteFooter">
<div class="container darkblue">
<div class="row">
<div class="twocol">
<h3>Experience</h3>
</div>
<div class="twocol">
<h3>Access</h3>
</div>
<div class="twocol">
<h3>Assistance</h3>
</div>
<div class="twocol">
<h3>Inquire</h3>
</div>
<div class="fourcol last">
<h3>Connect</h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container darkerblue">
<div class="twocol">
<ul>
<li><a href="/Experience-Avalon/">Avalon Choice Cruising</a></li>
<li><a href="/Cruise-Vacations/">Our Cruises</a></li>
<li><a href="/River-Cruise-Ships/">Our Fleet</a></li>
<li><a href="/interactive-suite/">Photos & Videos</a></li>
<li><a href="/Affiliations/">Awards and Affiliations</a></li>
</ul>
</div></div></div>
</center>
```

Comment: If this is a language that supports PCRE you need to set the "dot all" modifier

Comment: I don't know what language you're using for this, but regardless, Regex really is not the right tool for parsing HTML.  You might have a look at CsQuery or the Html Agility Pack.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16006543/618649

Comment: I advise reading [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) before going much further.

Comment: what exactly do you want to find?

Comment: Basically this is the footer from my page and when it comes in to this vendor application it messes a lot of things up so I just want to remove my entire footer. The 3rd party vendor is a mobile application site, so I just want to remove that entire footer or center so it doesnt even get loaded into the application.

Comment: Are you trying to do this on the server, or in the browser?  If you're doing this in the browser, I'd just use jQuery, grab the right div with a CSS selector and get rid of it:  `$("div[id='blah']").html("")` or some such thing...  If you're on the server, find an appropriate HTML parser for your platform (ASP.NET?  PHP?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use

```
<center>[\s\S]+?</center>
```

or turn on `singleline` or `DOTALL` mode if available so `.` matches any character *including* newlines,

```
(?s)<center>.+?</center>
```

The way that you turn on `singleline` mode varies with the language/tool, but adding `(?s)` to the start of the regex will work with many of them (but not Javascript).

*Further to comments*

It would be better to include the opening `div` tag to make sure you're removing the right `center` element. I.e.

```
<center>\s*<div id="divSiteFooter">[\s\S]+?</center>
```

Comment: Awesome this worked perfectly. The site even works like I imagined it was breaking because of that reason!

Comment: Regex is still honestly the *wrong* tool to use for parsing HTML.  Fair warning. :-)

Comment: That's assuming there isn't a `</center>` somewhere in the footer (thus the tags are basically exactly as provided, with little to no change of variation). Since it's a footer, there may not be any / much other data following it, so `+` instead of `+?` may be better. Or extend the check to include the 3 `</div>`'s as well, or similar. `[\s\S]` is a little strange, `(.|\n)` is more clear.

Comment: @Dukeling. Yes, it assumed there was only one center element in the _page_. I don't agree that just `+` would be better than `+?` or that the check should be extended to the three divs. `(.|\n)` uses a capture group unnecessarily and doesn't always match `\r`.

Comment: @MikeM It's easy enough to make it a non-capturing group (`?:` in Java for example). Then `(.|\r|\n)`, or, depending on the language, there may be an option to allow wildcards to include new-lines which may be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried regex modifier (or matching mode) multiline to search through newlines?

http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html#multi