# Get <element> inner content by class with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get the **myTEXT** of every `<td>` element with `myClass` class.

Example: `<td class="myClass" colspan="3">myTEXT</td>`

I tried with something like [Using regex to get text between multiple HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005413/using-regex-to-get-text-between-multiple-html-tags) but i had to filter by *myClass*.

I am new to lookahead, i was able to match using `(?=(<td.*)class="myClass".*?>){1}(.*?)<\/td>`, but it includes the `<td(...)>`and `</td>`.

So my question is, how can i get only the text **between** every `<td>` using *myClass* class?

Comment: If you are parsing HTML, there are better ways then using RegEx.  Or if you have to use a regex and it is a single line by itself you could use 
^\s*\<td.*\>(?<text>.*)\</td>$
where text becomes the name of the capture group.

Comment: Yes, it is to parse HTML. Also you suggestion returns an error: http://regexr.com/3f165

Comment: SInce  you asked as a c# question, I used .NET regular expression syntax. Tested with regexstorm and it seems to work

Comment: You really want to use [HTML Agiligy Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), instead of rolling your `regex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe... you can use this
http://html-agility-pack.net/

this one is support xpath grammar so you can use like this:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocumnet doc = new HtmlAgilityPath.HtmlDocumnet();
doc.LoadHtml(your html string);

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection col = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");
foreach(var node in col) {
    Console.WriteLine(node.OuterHtml);
}
```

I hope that this can help you.